# Data isolation by limiting access to subtrees in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have `Project1` and `Project2` as 'root nodes' with subtrees that could reach depth less than 10 (no node has a shortest path to the root node greater than length 10), but each could include millions of nodes. `Project1` subtree and `Project2` subtree have no connections between them. If I have two neo4j users, `project1-user` and `project2-user`, is there a simple and efficient way to limit the privileges of `project1-user` to the `Project1` subtree (and likewise for `project2-user`)? Privileges would include ALL (write, read, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RBAC, labels would be how you would restrict what you could MATCH or TRAVERSE. At the moment we don't support access based on graph topology (access only on nodes connecting to your project's root node).

Alternately, with Enterprise, you could create a separate graph per project, and only grant access to each project graph to the project's users. That gets you full isolation with no ability for anything to get overlooked (forgetting to add a label).